# How to re-run t4 templates that have a t4 extension instead of tt

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

This has to be something so simple I am really frustrated I can't find where it happens.

I just installed **EntityFramework 6.1.3** as well as **EntityFramework.CodeTemplates.CSharp** also **6.1.3**.

I want to modify the templates and run them so I first click Transfor All T4 Templates on the Build menu and then I right click both the Context.cs.t4 and EntityType.cs.t4 templaltes but the option "Run Custom Tool" is nowhere to be found.

I looked into the files' properties and tried setting the "Custom Tool" property of both files to "TextTemplatingFileGenerator" and as soon as I do that I get these compilation errors:

> Compiling transformation: Metadata file 'EntityFramework' could not be
>   found.
>   Compiling transformation: Metadata file
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design' could not be found.

On the EF samples that I am following from [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/dn753860) after installing the templates it mentions that the reverse engineer process can be run again but in order to do so apparently I would have to delete all the cs files that have been created before. Is that really necessary?

My final objective is to modify things so the entities are created in a separate project but all the solutions that I have found, obviously, talk about executing the t4 templates which is what I have not been able to do.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It should be `.tt` atleast in VS2013. `.t4` is not a known file extension. Try renaming the extension from `.t4` to `.tt`. It should give your option to run the template.

Comment: @vendettamit - I forgot to mention that on the question. I have already tried that and I get the exact same compilation errors as mentioned. My VS version is 2013 Update 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting because the default template installed via nugets doesn't know the IDE tools for entity framework. So you just need to change the following header values in `Context.cs.tt`:

```
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design" #>
<#@ assembly name="EntityFramework" #>
```

to:

```
<#@ assembly name="%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\EntityFramework.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.dll" #>
```

Now you'll get the legit error that parameter model is null.

**Update**

You're missing the 3rd step from the article you're referring. To run the `Reverse Engineer code first` you need to install [EF power tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) extension. After installation follow the steps:

Select the project **->** Right click **->** under EntityFramework **->** Reverse engineer code first. Select your database on which you want to run the custom templates.

These EF6 templates are parameterized templates you can't simply run them by right-click -> run custom tool. I think this is the reason the template file extension is renamed to `.t4` because these are specific to EF power tool only.

**Update 2**

I have modified the [EFPowerTool extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to support the namespace based directory structure creation. Created a pull [request](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/vendettamit/efdev/contribution/8721) on EF 6.x project at codeplex. Also I have created an [experimental branch](https://github.com/vendettamit/EFPowerTool) on github for testing purpose.(*There surely are room for fixes/enhancement which can be added and tested before sending updated pull request*)

You can download the extension installer with the proposed fix from [here](https://github.com/vendettamit/EFPowerTool). Hope this will help you fixing your issue for now.

Comment: Ok, so now I am getting the error you mention but it still hasn't solved the problem, even though I can now change the extension and choose the "Run Custom Tool" option, how do I get rid of this so the code executes properly?

Comment: Now you need to provide the values to the parameters defined in the template. Check out this link http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/ if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This has been a frustrating experience. It was not that I missed the step, I followed everything as it is described there. Nowhere does it say to install the power tools, the customization templates should have been obtained from them instead of where the documentation says, and by running the tool from there instead of modifying the entities that I had it created a new set inside of a Models folder and also created a group of Mappings which I do not know what they are for. Also it does not give me the choice to select which tables I want to use. :(

Comment: Yeah it is bit frustrating. I had to figure it out somehow. Also the nuget EF power tools doesn't use the nuget package t4 template. So you have to use option "Customize Reverse Engineer Template" to get the EF power tool t4 templates. Meanwhile I'm trying to figure out how to change the path for code generation.

Comment: @SergioRomero Check updates in the answer. Hope this will help you. Create bugs/issue/problem on github branch if you are interested in testing it.